# Sagemaker xgb.fit resulting in error: "User XXX is not authorized to perform: iam.GetRole on resource: role YYY"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to train an XGBoost model in SageMaker. I've manually created a role, named `sm_execution_role` in the AWS console and given it the trust relationship shown below, where arn:aws:iam::123456789016:user/user1 is the IAM user I want to authorize to perform sagemaker operations. I have run `aws configure` in the SageMaker terminal and input the access key and secret access key corresponding to user1.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "sagemaker.amazonaws.com",
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789016:user/user1"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

In a SageMaker notebook I'm trying to run the following code to generate an XGBoost model, but get the error shown. How can I resolve this?

```
role = 'sm_execution_role'
bucket_name = 'my_bucket'
prefix = 'SageMakerXGB'
containers = {'us-west-2': '433757028032.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest',
              'us-east-1': '811284229777.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest',
              'us-east-2': '825641698319.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest',
              'eu-west-1': '685385470294.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest'} 
my_region = boto3.session.Session().region_name
s3_input_train = sagemaker.s3_input(s3_data='s3://{}/{}/train'.format(bucket_name, prefix), content_type='csv')
sess = sagemaker.Session()
xgb = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(containers[my_region],role, train_instance_count=1, train_instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',output_path='s3://{}/{}/output'.format(bucket_name, prefix),sagemaker_session=sess)
xgb.set_hyperparameters(max_depth=5,eta=0.2,gamma=4,min_child_weight=6,subsample=0.8,num_round=100)
xgb.fit({'train': s3_input_train})
ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::123456789016:user/user1 is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role sm_execution_role
```

Comment: Which line gives the error? What policies are attached to the user1 role?

Comment: The last line gives the error. The sm_execution_role has the policies AmazonS3FullAccess and AmazonSageMakerFullAccess.

Comment: Have you tried adding a policy that allows the user to run `iam:GetRole`?

Comment: Turns out that user1 did not have AmazonSageMakerFullAccess permissions attached. After attaching that permission, I changed the code to say `role = get_execution_role()` (I no longer need sm_execution_role) and now it works.